# MailChimp API 3.0 batch request returns 400 Invalid Resource error

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I've been trying to use the [batch endpoint](http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/article/how-to-use-batch-operations) of MailChimp API (version 3.0) to subscribe new users to a list, but can't make it work.
Here is the request:

```
POST /3.0/batches

{
  "operations": [
    {
        "method" : "POST",
        "path" : "lists/c852ce5c86/members",
        "body": "{\"email_address\":\"email@domain.tld\", \"status\":\"subscribed\"}"
    }            
  ]
}
```

The request seems ok cause I get a 200 response:

```
{
  "id": "49abca6ef3",
  "status": "finished",
  "total_operations": 1,
  "finished_operations": 1,
  "errored_operations": 1,
  "submitted_at": "2015-09-21T18:11:16+00:00",
  "completed_at": "2015-09-21T18:11:23+00:00",
  "response_body_url": "https://mailchimp-api-batch.s3.amazonaws.com/49abca6ef3-response.tar.gz?..."
}
```

However, as you can see, the only operation in my batch is errored.

Here is the `response_body_url` for this operation:

```
[{
    "status_code":400,
    "operation_id":null,
    "response":"{
        \"type\":\"http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/error-docs/400-invalid-resource\",
        \"title\":\"Invalid Resource\",
        \"status\":400,
        \"detail\":\"The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the 'errors' array.\",
        \"instance\":\"\",
        \"errors\":[{
            \"field\":\"\",
            \"message\":\"Schema describes object, NULL found instead\"
        }]
    }"
}]
```

which is not very helpful :(

Note that if I directly hit `POST lists/c852ce5c86/members` with `{"email_address":"email@domain.tld", "status":"subscribed"}` payload, it's working properly.

Comment: This was an issue when the /batches endpoint was first released. This should work for you now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was actually a bug in the mailchimp API. After reaching them they quickly fixed it.

Comment: Ok, but where is the bug in the mailchimp api?